# About a particular use of hashing

Tags: complexity-theory, hash

Look at the last problem on page 2 here,
http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~khot/CSCI-GA.3350-001-2014/sol3.pdf

- All one wants to do is to convert a $x \in \{ 0,1\}^n$ into a $y \in \{0,1\}^k$ . Then just a linear transformation would have been enough. Why install this vector "b"?
- If $a_1,x_1,x_2 \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $b_1,y_1,y_2 \in \{0,1\}$ then why is demanding simultaneous satisfaction of the equations $a_1^Tx_1 + b_1 = y_1, a_1^Tx_2 + b_1 = y_2$ the same as claiming the simultaneous satisfaction of the equations, $a_1^T(x_1 \oplus x_2) = y, b_1 = y \oplus y_1$ ?( where $y = y_1 \oplus y_2$)

Comment: Please make your question self-contained: people shouldn't need to click through to read a separate PDF to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, the vector $b$ is necessary to make sure $\text{Pr}_{A,b}[\vec{a_1} x^{T} + b_1 = y] = 1/2$, for $k = 1$.

Otherwise, it is easy to see that $\text{Pr}_{A,b}[\vec{a_1} x^{T} = 0] = 3/4$ and $\text{Pr}_{A,b}[\vec{a_1} x^{T} = 1] = 1/4$, for $n=1$. By conditional probability and the law of total probability, we can get $\text{Pr}_{A,b}[\vec{a_1} x^{T} = 0] = 5/8$ and $\text{Pr}_{A,b}[\vec{a_1} x^{T} = 1] = 3/8$, for $n=2$. This approach can be generalized to arbitrary $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question: it's not equivalent.  $a_1^T x_1 + b_1 = y_1$, $a_1^T x_2 + b_1 = y_2$ is equivalent to $a_1^T(x_1 + x_2) = y_1 + y_2$, $b_1 = a_1^T x_1 + y_1$.

Why?  Well, if you subtract the two given equations from each other, you get $a_1^T x_1 - a_1^T x_2 = y_1 - y_2$.  If you now use the fact that subtraction is the same as addition when working modulo 2, then you get $a_1^T(x_1 + x_2) = y_1 + y_2$.  Also the equation about $b_1$ follows by simple manipulation of the first equation.

Conversely, if you know $a_1^T(x_1 + x_2) = y_1 + y_2$ and $a_1^T(x_1 + x_2) = y_1 + y_2$, then through similar algebraic manipulations you can conclude $a_1^T x_1 + b_1 = y_1,$ $a_1^T x_2 + b_1 = y_2$.

Comment: But the way you have decomposed the equations the effect of $a_1$ and $b_1$ have not been decoupled. The idea is to show that  over independent random choices of $a_1$ and $b_1$ the probability of the first pair of the equations being satisfied is the same as product of the individual satisfaction probabilities of the later two equations.